# Let $B={b_1, b_2, ... , b_n}$ be a basis for a vector space V. Prove that each v ∈ V can be expressed as a linear combination of $b_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

such that

$v = \alpha_1 b_1 + \alpha_2 b_2 + ... + \alpha_n b_n  $

in only one way that the coordinates of $\alpha_i$ are unique.

Am I right to assume that this question is asking to prove that B is linearly independent? I know that this must be the case for B to be a basis by definition, but how exactly do I prove this mathematically without sounding redundant?

Comment: *Am I right to assume that this question is asking to prove that B is linearly independent?* No. Here, you're showing that the basis spans the space $V$.  What definition of a basis are you given?

Comment: Well my understanding of a basis is that for a vector space V, $S={v_1, v_2, ..., v_n}$ is a finite set of vectors in V, then S is a basis if, S is linearly independent, and S spans V

Answer (score 2):

This question is not asking you to prove that $B$ is linearly independent. It is asking you to show that if 
$$
v=\alpha_1 b_1+\dotsb+\alpha_n b_n\tag{1}
$$
and 
$$
v=\alpha_1^\prime b_1+\dotsb+\alpha_n^\prime b_n\tag{2}
$$
then $\alpha_i=\alpha_i^\prime$. In other words, the question is asking you to show that for each vector $v$ the coordinates of $v$ relative to the basis $B$ are unique.

Now, to show this, note that subtracting (2) from (1) gives 
$$
\mathbf 0=(\alpha_1-\alpha_1^\prime)b_1+\dotsb+(\alpha_n-\alpha_n^\prime)b_n\tag{3}
$$
What facts do we know about $B$ that allows us to infer useful information from equation (2)?

Comment: We know B is linearly independent, so (α1−α′1) must be 0. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this gives you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a contradiction proof: suppose there exist two different sets of coordinates that give you the same v; then take the difference of those two equations and obtain a contradiction against the fact that basis vectors should be linearly independent. Hope this helps.